# how to serve static files via MVC after login (I am trying to add an angular mini-SPA to my large MVC project)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, model-view-controller

Looking for suggestions on how to host static files through an MVC app.

I have an MVC SPA (basically a bunch of static html, js and img files). I want users to be able to access these static files only after they have logged into my MVC application. I am running on a windows server platform, using IIS.

Currently I am doing this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("AngularApp/{*path}"); //to serve up angular files from AngularApp folder
```

However this has a number of problems.

I don't really want to ignore the route, I want the MVC controller to check if the user has permissions (like my other controllers do), if not redirect to login page and if so, then instead of sending them to a view, allow them to load any files in a particular folder or subfolders. But the folders these files load from need to be a different path than the route URL requested. For example I don't want users to have to go to mysite.com/angularseedapp/deploy/app/mypage.html but rather if they request mysite.com/a/mypage.html I want it to serve up the file from there.

This seems simply a matter of being able to have MVC redirect and fetch files from a different folder, but I have no idea how to do this.

Could someone knowledgeable about MVC please give me a step by step simple way to do this? When I try to fetch files outside the views folder this seemingly simple task results in various permissions and other kinds of errors because I don't know how to do it correctly.

Thanks!

P.S. To clarify, I know how to get my controller to check permissions and redirect, to any single file in the views folder, but how do I do it for a whole folder of files and directories in a higher level folder? I want to map the route, have it go to a controller, then instead of going to a view I want it to take me to static files. I suspect there is some way to use maproute() in global.asax to help me do this but I do not have a lot of experience with that.

Comment: One way I have seen it done is by having a separate application that holds all your static files. That in turn is then hosted on IIS when you need a file you make a service call which will take your request and respond with a link to the resource. Then just open the resource as needed. Would be one way to do it. This also gets you away from having to maintain all the static stuff in your project along with the actual code. Instead you can have a dedicated project to house videos, documents, images etc.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that would be good except if its a separate project hosted by IIS how can I control permissions like who can access it through my MVC app permission scheme?

Answer (score 0):

I may be oversimplifying but I usually select the application in IIS Manager and then select Mime Types, they add mappings for whatever types you want to map statically.  I've done this for HTML and JSON files before and it worked fine. Use type = text/javascript or application/json etc.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to control routes and permissions to such static files via controller code - I need to be able to deny access to these files for some users.